# While loop and ranged numbers in python

Tags: python, while-loop, numbers, range, date-range

Working on a code for school in which I need to modify it to only allow for an input range of 0 to 20o by the user. This is the code so far. Every time I try and place a while loop it doesn't work and I can still enter any value higher than 200. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import turtle  #allows access to a collection of Python functions that make it possible to draw

Jane = turtle.Turtle()  #creates a "turtle" to do our drawing for us; we will call the turtle Jane

# the next four lines get input from the user so we know how tall to make the bars in the graph

bar1 = int(input("What is the height of the first bar?" ))

bar2 = int(input("What is the height of the second bar?" ))

bar3 = int(input("What is the height of the third bar?" ))
  
bar4 = int(input("What is the height of the fourth bar? "))
 
#the turtle always starts out facing left; the next line rotates it so it faces up

Jane.left(90)

#next we will create a function that will draw one bar of the bar graph

#the function requires us to pass the height of the bar into it

def bar(height):
    
    #Jane will make a line that is as long as the height that the user inputted
    
    Jane.forward(height)
    
    #now we will turn Jane to the left to make the top of the bar
    
    Jane.left(90)
    
    #now Jane needs to more forward to draw the top of the bar
    
    Jane.forward(20)
    
    #now Jane needs to turn left 
     
    Jane.left(90)
    
    #now Jane needs to draw a line that is as long as the height
    
    Jane.forward(height)
    
    #now Jane needs to rotate 180 degrees to be ready for the next bar
    
    Jane.right(180)

#now we will call the function four times--one for each bar. Notice that

#we will go in the order 4-3-2-1, since the bars will be drawn from right to left

bar(bar4)

bar(bar3)

bar(bar2)

bar(bar1)
```

Comment: There's nothing in here that tries to limit the range.  Do you need to limit ALL of the inputs?  If so, then the obvious answer is to create a function, maybe called `limited_input`, that accepts a prompt string as a parameter.  It can do the while loop and keep doing the prompt until the value is within range.

Comment: Where can't you place a while loop, where do you want to place a while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
def limit_input(prompt):
    while True:
        value = int(input(prompt))
        if value < 200:
            return value
        print( "Please keep your value below 200.")

bar1 = limit_input("What is the height of the first bar?")
bar2 = limit_input("What is the height of the second bar?")
bar3 = limit_input("What is the height of the third bar?")
bar4 = limit_input("What is the height of the fourth bar?")
```

An exercise left to the reader is to add a `try`/`except ValueError` clause to catch when the user types something other than a number.

Comment: Don't you need `return value` rather than just `return`?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this code. I think the code like this you are looking for.

```
import turtle

Jane = turtle.Turtle()

bars = []
for i in range(4):
    height = 201
    while height > 200:
        height = int(input(f'What is the height of the {i + 1}. bar? (from 1 to 200))'))
    bars.append(height)

Jane.left(90)


def bar(height):
    Jane.forward(height)
    Jane.left(90)
    Jane.forward(20)
    Jane.left(90)
    Jane.forward(height)
    Jane.right(180)


for b in bars:
    bar(b)
```

Comment: Or `for b in bars:` / `bar(b)`.  Virtually every time you write `for x in range(len(y)):` (which is essentially what you wrote), there is a better way.

Comment: you are right. I am editing the code. Thank you.